# TortoiseSVN Commit failed. Error: Can't close file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a problem with `TortoiseSVN Commit`. On Friday everything was working fine, but today I can't commit. The error is:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):   Error: Can't close file  
Error: 
'\\fileserver\Shared\GEO\DESARROLLO\SHARED_DES\DESARROLLO_IT\Proyectos
Error: 
2014\Web\SistemaIntegradoSeguridad_SVN\db\transactions\68-2w.txn\changes':
Error:  Acceso denegado.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark here and guessing that _Acceso denegado_ translates to _Access Denied_. Have any security settings changed on your SVN server?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like your repo is being shared out by a file server (i.e. SMB/CIFS). You shouldn't do that - it is not supported, and issues like this are notoriously common.

Comment: I read your comments, the problem is that all was working, and now no. The only changes I made is install Kaspersky Antivirus.